# How to add a vertical line to the left of Table of Content, including sections but excluding the chapter (as attached pic)

Tags: table-of-contents

[image]I am stuck on adding a vertical line on the left of the sections in the table of content (using Latex-Overleaf). The line should not include the chapter title.
What i mean is shown in the attached picture.

here is a sample code, in case required:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{report}
    
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Project Introduction}
\section{Section A}
\section{subsection A}

\chapter{Case Study 2}
\section{Section A}
\section{Section B}
\section{Section C}
\section{Section D}
\section{subsection A}
\section{subsection A}

\end{document}
```

Many thanks in advance,

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the entries are single liners this can be done easily using the `entrynumberformat` feature of ToC entry style `toclines` of [package `tocbasic`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocbasic):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{report}
\usepackage{tocbasic}

\newcommand*{\numberwithbar}[1]{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{.1pt}{\baselineskip}\enskip#1}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[entrynumberformat=\numberwithbar]{tocline}{section}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Project Introduction}
\section{Section A}
\section{subsection A}

\chapter{Case Study 2}
\section{Section A}
\section{Section B}
\section{Section C}
\section{Section D}
\section{subsection A}
\section{subsection A}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: If you also have subsections or lower levels in the ToC you have to adapt the entries of those, too, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{report}
\usepackage{tocbasic}

\newcommand*{\numberwithbar}[2]{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{.1pt}{\baselineskip}\hspace{#1}#2}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[entrynumberformat=\numberwithbar{.5em}]{tocline}{section}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[indent:=section,numwidth=4em,entrynumberformat=\numberwithbar{1.5em}]{tocline}{subsection}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Project Introduction}
\section{Section A}
\section{subsection A}

\chapter{Case Study 2}
\section{Section A}
\section{Section B}
\section{Section C}
\section{Section D}
\subsection{subsection A}
\subsection{subsection A}

\end{document}
```

However, this very simple suggestion would not work, if an entry needs more than one line!

Comment: That is what i needed, thank you very much